# Robot Framework : How to handle the "Select a Certificate" popup which is having multiple certificates in chrome?

Tags: robotframework

**Robot Framework: How to handle the "Select a Certificate" popup which is having multiple certificates in chrome and selecting a specific certificate and clicking on OK?**

We have code using Sikuli but the code is not working for headless mode.

**Expectation: Code should run in head/headless mode without any issues by using  Robot framework selenium libraries or any other libraries.**

Scenario: I have multiple certificates for the website and have to choose a specific certificate according to the scenario select 1 at a time and click on ok.

**["Select a Certificate" popup] Image Link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJnYq.png**

**Note:**

1. Tried adding certificate details in Registry Key. As it will handle multiple certificates. But if we need to understand which certificate is taken from the entry key.

**Please help on finding the specific code to handle in the Robot framework.**